# "look at me for a long time" vs "look long at me"

Tags: phrase-usage

> I’m a bit shy when you **look at me for a long time**.
>
> I’m a bit shy when you **look long at me**.

Are both sentences idiomatic? As I understand them, they have the same meaning. Right?

Comment: In AmE, only the first is ok (it's not an idiom though and it sounds unusual). The second one is not idiomatic or grammatical.

Comment: The second one might be found in a poem or the lyrics of a song rather than in a grammatical construction.

Comment: Yes, "long" can function adverbially: "I've long wondered about that." "Don't wait long." However, it is only used in certain situations, and your second sentence, unfortunately, is not one of those.

Comment: Are you trying to say. "stare", q.v.?